# How to fix the table rows with and without data

Tags: reporting-services

I need to fix 20 rows in my table.. The data shown in 10 rows i want to create remaining 10 rows dynamically

If the tablix data length is 10 rows I need to show the 20 rows data rows and 10 rows blank rows

Answer (score 1):

I've done this in the past within the query.  What I've done is add the relevant data into a temporary table.  With that table, you can then get a `COUNT` of how many rows exist and add empty rows until you get 20 total.  So for example, you might add something like the following.

```
DECLARE @rowCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temporaryTable)

WHILE @rowCount < 20
  BEGIN
   INSERT INTO #temporaryTable(someField)
     VALUES (' ')
     SET @rowCount = @rowCount + 1
  END
```

As there's very little information about your data, you'll have to adjust this to match your data but the idea is the same.  After you have all the rows you need, simply end the procedure with

```
SELECT * FROM #temporaryTable
```